# Distinguish between clicking the displayed item and clicking an item in the drop-down list in a ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, events, combobox

I would like to know how to distinguish between clicking the displayed item and clicking one of the items in the drop-down list of the ComboBox.

Comment: What `DropDownStyle` is the ComboBox using?

Comment: @Matthew Watson comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... distinguish between clicking the displayed item and clicking one of the items in the drop-down list

I assume that you want to know if the operator re-selects the last selected items (which is the displayed item), or selects a new item (which is in the drop-down list.

You need a property to access the item that the operator selected:

```
private MyType SelectedItem => (MyType)this.comboBox1.SelectedValue;

private MyType LastProcessedSelectedItem {get; set;} = null;

private void OnOperatorSelectedItem(MyType selectedItem)
{
    if (this.LastProcessedSelectedItem != selectedItem)
    {
        this.OperatorSelectedDropDown();
    }
    else
    {
         this.OperatorSelectedDisplayed();
    }
    this.LastProcessedSelectedItem = selectedItem;
}

private void OnComboBox1_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    MyType selectedItem = this.SelectedItem;
    OnOperatorSelectedItem(selectedItem);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I assumed that there is a built in event to distinguish these two kinds of selection clicks.